# Rails input from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controller

In rails how do you get information from view to use in a controller. Like if i have a page with a text field and a button, how would i send the value from the field (without a model) into my controller to work with it in one of my functions. Im using rails 3

Comment: Post the code for your view and the controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you could use a simple form, for example:

in your `views/products/index.html.erb`:

```
<% form_tag omg_products_path do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :my_input %>
    <%= submit_tag "Send input" %>
<% end %>
```

in your `controllers/products_controller.rb`:

```
def omg
    my_input = params['my_input']
    #do whatever you want with my_input
end
```

You will also want to configure `routes.rb`, for example like this:

```
resources :products do
    post :omg, :on => :collection
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will still want a model, but just use a **Non Active Record Model** see this Rails Cast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/121-non-active-record-model